# Multiple columns with one alias

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns, alias

How can I group a set of columns under one alias?

For example, if I wanted to have Demographics as an alias for the group of columns: First_name, Last_name, Gender, DOB, and AGE from TEST table. I don't want to group the columns into one column. I want them in separate columns but under one alias which is Demographics. Reason I am asking is if I wanted to join the Demographics with another alias that has a set of columns from another table. In excel it would look like the image attached.

Sorry in advance for not composing a syntax. I've tried using the t1, t2 method but the results isn't what I want. [image: Result to show like this]

Comment: That sounds like a handy feature, but it's not one supported by Oracle or any other RDBMS out there. You'll have to type out each column you want in your ON clause.

Comment: @JNevill . . . Some databases support record types, which sort of does this.  However, no SQL-based database supports two levels of headers.

Comment: Since you are using Oracle, this might be an option for you...[Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm)

Comment: Ah! That could be a good start. Thank you @clinomaniac. Thank you everyone else for providing feedback.

Comment: I see that @clinomaniac has given you the link to Oracle 10g documentation. Oracle objects have been around since Oracle 8 and have evolved since then. I suggest you go to the documentation for the Oracle version that you are using. All the Oracle documentation for all the versions is available online via Oracle's Web site.